# Does Sidekiq share the same database connection pool as puma

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, sidekiq

I am running a production app with

```
rails 6.0.3. 
Puma currently runs with 1 worker and 5 threads.
Also the database connection pool is set to 5 in config/database.yml.
mysql: 5.7
```

It all works fine until we recently introduced sidekiq worker with concurrency of `8`.
So to make sure, that all 8 threads of sidekiq are able to get an open connection in worst case, we increased the pool size to 8 in config/database.yml

My question is does sidekiq worker share the same database pool with puma worker.
So suppose, if all the 8 connection pools are being utilised by 8 sidekiq threads , and at the same time there comes a web request, will it result in a ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError.

If they dont share the same pool, the error should not come up.
I want to understand the behaviour. Also I understand two workers of puma have their own local pools. They dont share it.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

They are separate processes; each process gets 8 connections.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the application getting a connection timeout error shall be because your database is configured to handle a maximum set of connections at a given instance.
All the database connections via Puma are totally independent of the connections Sidekiq makes with your database.
It is on your database service, how many connections it can handle at a given time. If there is some extra request, the database service will reject the connection request.